# Upload `Encrypted ` file to azure container and `Decrypt` on the other end - using Angular

Tags: angular, azure-blob-storage

I am building an `Angular` application where I am uploading the file to `Azure Container` and also able to fetch it and see.

Next, I need help how to:

- upload the `Encrypted` image to `Azure Container`? and,
- want to fetch, decrypt and be able to see?

Comment: How will you share the encryption key?

Comment: I am getting the encryption key from the azure key vault - so that's not an issue.

Comment: Maybe you can get some tips and ideas from something like this series of posts: https://damienbod.com/2020/10/22/using-encrypted-access-tokens-in-azure-with-microsoft-identity-web-and-azure-app-registrations/

Comment: Have you referred this https://tech-tutes.com/2021/02/25/encrypt-and-decrypt-storage-account-blobs-using-azure-key-vault/ or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-encrypt-decrypt-blobs-key-vault?tabs=dotnet